# Discord JDA - Timed Mutes

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I'm trying to find a way to make timed mutes. Currently, I am saving the data to a JSON file that includes the length in seconds and the date the mute was issued. Previously, I used a simple .queueAfter() method but feel this wouldn't be good enough in the future. Can someone explain a simple way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) to store the final date (using the `plus()` method to implement minutes/hours to the date).
Then use [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) with `scheduleAtFixedRate()` to compare the current Instant and your stored Instant.